# Java: ArrayLists w/ Scanner: First element not printing

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

I was trying to make a program that prints out user-inputted values in an `ArrayList`, and for the most part, it works. Except it does not print the first element. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Family {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the names of your immediate family members and enter \"done\" when you are finished.");
        String x=in.nextLine();
        while(!(x.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))){
            x = in.nextLine();
            names.add(x);

        }
        int location = names.indexOf("done");
        names.remove(location);
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

For example if, I enter jack, bob, sally, it'll print [bob, sally]

Comment: FYI, you don't need the 2-step `indexOf()` and `remove()`. `names.remove("done")` will do the trick.

Comment: user did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `nextLine()` immediately when you enter the loop, losing the previously inputted line in the process. You should use it before reading an additional value:

```
while (!(x.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))) {
    names.add(x);
    x = in.nextLine();            
}
```

EDIT:
This, of course, means that `"done"` won't be added to `names`, so the following lines, and they should be removed:

```
int location = names.indexOf("done");
names.remove(location);
```

Comment: @EduardoDennis Sure it does.

Comment: @shmosel it gives arrayIndexOutofBounds I just tried it. look at the line where he is doing names.remove the index will be higher than the size of the array list.

Comment: @EduardoDennis those lines should, of course, be removed - I've edited it into my answer.

Comment: of course ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ you and @shmosel should upvote my question because I was right :D

Comment: @shmosel it wasnt working, there I removed it ahah lets become allies since we are always in the Java questions :) I even gave upvote

Comment: @EduardoDennis Sure thing. You know I got your back.

Comment: @shmosel ahahah ^>^

Answer (score 1):

```
String x=in.nextLine();
```

this line outside the `while loop` consumes first input because as you enter the `while loop`, you again call `x=in.nextLine();` without saving the first input, so it gets lost. Hence it doesn't gets printed because its not in the `ArrayList`.

Just remove `String x=in.nextLine();` that is included before the `while loop` and your code will work fine.

```
String x="";

System.out.println("Enter the names of your immediate family members and enter \"done\" " +
"when you are finished.");

while(!(x.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))){
    x = in.nextLine();
    names.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because the first element is consumed by the first `x= in.nextLine();` and you never added it to the list.

Try this:

```
 System.out.println("Enter the names of your immediate family members and enter \"done\" when you are finished.");
        String x="";
        while(!(x.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))){
            x = in.nextLine();
            names.add(x);

        }
```